# check String for consecutive zero's

Tags: python, function

I want to make a func that return the amount of consecutive zero's.

```
print(consecutive_zeros("0100100001"))
```

should return 4

```
def consecutive_zeros(string):
    zeros = 0
    cache = 0
    for elem in range(len(string)):
        if string[elem] == "0":
            zeros += 1
        elif string[elem] == "1":
            if zeros > cache:
                zeros = cache
                zeros = 0
        return cache
```

My func always returns 0 if i give it a string with numbers

```
for elem in range(len(string)):
    if string[elem] == "0":
        zeros += 1
```

This should count every 0

```
elif string[elem] == "1":
        if zeros > cache:
            zeros = cache
```

This breaks the counter when 1 appearing and checks if the amount of the counted
consecutive zeros is higher as the momentarily saved zeros

Comment: Your func doesn't return anything

Comment: Also, I think you meant `cache = zeros`. And you need to set `zeros` to `0` when you find `"1"`

Comment: And another thing. Read about [for loops](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp). You can iterate over `string` directly (i.e. `for elem in string`) and avoid indexing the string (i.e. `if elem == "0":`)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really a Python guy, but I'd just use a regex here.

```
txt = "0100100001"

# Find all sub strings with 2 or more consecutive zeros
matches = re.findall("00+", txt)

# Compute string lengths
lengths = map(lambda x: len(x), matches)

# Find Longest
max_zeros = max(lengths);

print(max_zeros)
```

Comment: or to make it as a one-liner `max([len(p) for p in re.findall("00+",strs)])`

Comment: I am really new to programming in general so i have no idear what a regex is

Comment: @marco Learning regex is a big bite, but worth it as it works in most languages.
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fix of your code:

```
def consecutive_zeros(string):
    zeros = 0
    cache = 0
    for elem in string:
        if elem == "0":
            zeros += 1
            if zeros > cache:
                cache = zeros # this was inverted
        else:
                zeros = 0
    return cache # this was wrongly indented

consecutive_zeros("01001000010")
```

output: `4`

I would personally use `itertools.groupby` and a comprehension:

```
from itertools import groupby 

s = '0100100001'

max(len(list(g)) for v,g in groupby(s) if v=='0')
```

output: `4`

Comment: I cant make it work; "0101000101010010" returns 5

Comment: @CutePoison I provided a fix (and a better approach IMO)

Answer (score 0):

You also need to check the current count after you finished the iteration, in case the max consecutive appearances is in the last sequence.

```
def consecutive_zeros(string):
    curr = 0
    max_consecutive_zeros = 0
    for ch in string:
        if ch == '0':
            curr += 1
            continue
        else:
            if curr >= max_consecutive_zeros:
                max_consecutive_zeros = curr
            curr = 0
    if curr >= max_consecutive_zeros:
        max_consecutive_zeros = curr
    return maxmax_consecutive_zeros    
max_consecutive_zeros = consecutive_zeros("0100100001")

print(max_consecutive_zeros)
>> 4
```

Comment: please **dont** use `max` as variable name!

Answer (score 0):

See @Nick B for a great (and fast!) answer.

But, if you want to use your solution;

1. Your function returns after the first loop - move your `return` such that it's aligned with your `for` loop

```py
def consecutive_zeros(string):
    zeros = 0
    cache = 0
    for elem in range(len(string)):
        if string[elem] == "0":
            zeros += 1
        elif string[elem] == "1":
            if zeros > cache:
                zeros = cache
                zeros = 0
    return cache #Aligned it such that data is returned at last
```

2. Your function returns `cache` which is never updated; you need to update that

```py
def consecutive_zeros(string):
    zeros = 0
    cache = 0
    for elem in range(len(string)):
        if string[elem] == "0":
            zeros += 1
        elif string[elem] == "1":
            if zeros > cache:
                cache = zeros #'zeros = cache' before
                zeros = 0
    return cache #Aligned it such that data is returned at last
```

3. Your code does not reset `zeros` - only when `zeros>cache`. Move `zeros=0` outside the `if zeros > cache` but such that's still in the `elif string[elem] == "1"`

```py
def consecutive_zeros(string):
    zeros = 0
    cache = 0
    for elem in range(len(string)):
        if string[elem] == "0":
            zeros += 1
        elif string[elem] == "1":
            if zeros > cache:
                cache = zeros #'zeros = cache' before
            zeros = 0 #Move it such that it's updated whenever we reset our counter
    return cache #Aligned it such that data is returned at last
```

and then it works

4. Note, use `for elem in string` instead of `for elem in range(len(string))`

Answer (score 0):

In case your string just contains `0` and `1`'s, you could:

```
data = "0100100001"
print(max(len(x) for x in data.split('1')))
```

Print:

```
4
```